Create/ Install MSI file created using CX_FREEZE without ADMIN rights
I want to distribute a Python project and so I created a MSI file using CX_FREEZE. The requested commands are:
executable = [Executable(
    'main.py',
    base = 'Win32GUI',
    target_name = exe_name,
    icon = 'icon.ico',
    shortcut_name = exe_name
    )]

build_exe_options = {
    'build_exe': 'build/' + dir_name,
    'optimize': 2
}

build_msi_options = {
    'target_name': project_name,
    'install_icon': 'icon.ico'
}

setup(
    name = project_name,
    version = version,
    author = author,
    options={
        'build_exe': build_exe_options,
        'build_msi': build_msi_options
    },
    executables = executable,
)

This creates a MSI file with the asked name, however when I try to install it, admin rights are needed. This project will be deployed in systems where users might not have admin rights. Any way to bypass this?
